# 質問や回答に対するコメントの編集履歴や削除した痕跡がみえないのはなぜ？

Tags: 討議

[webサーバーからスマホアプリの操作](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/23068/web%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9E%E3%83%9B%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%81%AE%E6%93%8D%E4%BD%9C/23069#23069)

この回答に対して

[@KenjiNoguchi](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/7837/)　さんという方から
「SSL proxy を利用して httpsパケットスニッフィングをすればリクエストとレスポンスが丸見えです。アプリ開発者ならだれもやっている」

というコメント(完全には覚えていないのでだいたいの内容。HTTPSパケットスニッフィングという単語が出てきたことが印象的でした)が、これはかなり有益な情報だと思って感動していたのですが、なぜかこのコメントをみた１時間後くらいにコメントが削除されてしましました。
まさか削除されるとは思わなくてスクリーンショットは撮っていませんでした。

かなり有益なコメントだったのでもう一度みたいと思いましたが、このサイトってコメントの編集と削除の履歴が残らない仕様のようで困っています。

一般的にはコメントや発言などには一定の責任があるかもしれないので、編集履歴や削除したことを示すメッセージ程度は表示してほしいのですが、なぜこのサイトではその機能がないのでしょうか？　一般的な質問サイトでは投稿した質問やメッセージは責任があるため削除や編集などに対して割りと厳し目の措置がとられています(Yahoo知恵袋, LINE Q, など)。

**Yahoo知恵袋**

> [自分が投稿した「質問」を取り消したい場合](http://www.yahoo-help.jp/app/answers/detail/a_id/41770/p/530#fix)
>   解決済みの質問を削除したい場合 Yahoo!プレミアム会員のみ、解決済みの質問をご自身で削除できます。
>   削除できるのは、月に1回、1件です。（例：1月31日に削除した場合、2月1日から削除可能になります。）
>   また、削除は、ウェブページからのみ行えます。アプリからは削除できません。 なお、Yahoo! JAPAN
>   IDを削除済みの場合、質問は削除できません。
>
> [自分が投稿した「回答」を取り消したい場合](http://www.yahoo-help.jp/app/answers/detail/a_id/41775/p/530)
>   ・回答を取り消すと、回答した際にプラスされた知恵コイン15枚がマイナスされます。 ・画像のみの削除、取り消しはできません。
>   ・回答を投稿したYahoo! JAPAN IDまたはニックネームの変更はできません

**LINE Q**

> [ヘルプセンター | LINE](https://help2.line.me/LINEQ/web/pc?lang=ja)
>   回答は削除できますか？ 一度投稿した回答を削除することはできません。
>   ただし、回答が禁止行為等に該当する場合、予告なしに運営者が回答を削除することがあります。

個人的にはコメントも投稿者としての責任がありトレースされるべきだと思っています
みなさまの考えをきかせてください

Comment: 編集日時をクリックすれば回答の編集履歴は見えます。確かスコアがある一定以上の人には削除履歴も見えます。実際当該の質問で猫カフェさんご自身が回答・削除されていますね。ところで内容が具体的整理されたとは言え基本的に[同一内容で質問を立ち上げ、ご自身で回答までされています](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/23090/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9E%E3%83%9B%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%81%AE%E9%9D%9E%E5%85%AC%E9%96%8Bapi%E3%82%92%E8%AA%BF%E3%81%B9%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF)。元の質問の内容を編集したほうが有益だったのではないでしょうか。

Comment: [「モデレーター ツールへのアクセス」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)権限を持つユーザーは削除済みの質問・回答を見ることができますね。♦モデレーターはそれに加えて、削除済みのコメントも見ることができます。

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi さん、スコアに応じて履歴が見れるというのは知りませんでした。回答有り難うございます。「回答を削除して」これは、「ほぼ同一の内容だが違う目的の質問を立ち上げ」るためです。元の質問の内容とはまた別の目的を持った質問だと判断したため新しく質問しました。元の質問の内容は「スマホの代理投稿をしているウェブサービスはどういった仕組みでスマホアプリを操作しているのか」という質問ですので親戚のような関係になりますが「スマホアプリの非公開APIを調べるには？」とはまったく別の質問です。したがって元の質問の内容を修正するよりも新しく投稿したほうが私にとって有益でした。

Answer (score 2):

StackOverflowのシステムとしては、コメントは質問や回答に対する指摘をするためのもので、ここに重要な事が書かれることは期待していないはずです。履歴が残らないのはその必要が無いからでしょう。

システムを知らないでコメントに質問の補足情報を書いたり回答をしている人がいますが、質問を編集して追記する、回答として投稿することを促してあげましょう。もしくは、システム上認められているので自分でやってしまいましょう。回答として転記する場合は、「コミュニティwiki」のチェックを付けておくと誰にも点が入らなくなります。

Answer (score 1):

コメントの責任、という概念について: そこまでの責任を負いたい訳ではないから、コメントにしているのではないか(回答ではなく)、と率直に思っています。

また、仮に責任の概念を持ち出したならば、責任があるからこそ、削除したくなる場合はあるかと思います。(いい例かはわかりませんが、ツイッターでツイート削除機能は、ほしいですよね。。？)

また、例示されている引用は、「質問」や「回答」に対する規約(?)であって、コメントについての規約ではなさそうですが、、

Comment: そうなんですよね。回答とコメントの線引がけっこう曖昧でコメントに責任をおうべきか判断しかねます。でもこの回答についたコメントは意見というよりはかなり回答に近いメッセージでしたので、そのようなコメントが一方的に削除されていいものなのかとも疑問に思っているんです

Answer (score 0):

コメントを削除、というか移動した本人です。回答・コメントは自分の勉強と後から読んだ人の何らかの利益を願って書いています（個人的な感想も多いですけど）。

当該のコメントは猫カフェさんの推測が多分に含まれた回答に当初つけましたが、質問者さんに直接したほうがより有益と思ったので、移しました。また、猫カフェさんの回答は現在-3でこのまま行くと僕のコメントも一緒に埋もれてしまい、質問主さんが読む機会を失うと思ったのも移動した理由です。

Comment: 「質問者さんに直接したほうがより有益と思ったので、移しました」これはコミュニティにとって有益な情報を提供するということで理解できるのですが「また、猫カフェさんの回答は現在-2でこのまま行くと僕のコメントも一緒に埋もれてしまいますので」このひとことは議論にとって余計ですしそもそも健全な人格を持っている人ならば書かないと思いますし、自分の利益を天秤にかけて利益の出る方に移動したとも感じられるのは私だけでしょうか？

Comment: 言葉が足りなかったので更新しました。気分を害されたならすみません。スタックオバーフローに書き込んで僕の直接の利益になることは何もありませんので天秤云々は理解できません。

Comment: いえ、ちょっと個人的でデリケートな問題も含んでいるのでこちらも一方的過ぎたと思います。とはいえ、Kenjiさんは非常に豊富な知識量や卓越した洞察力をお持ちなのにコメントの受けてがその発言によりどのような感情を抱くのかを想像できていないのは非常に惜しいと思いました。インターネットという匿名性の高い世界に生きる以上、相手の顔が見えないからこそ価値観の押し付けや一方的な主張で離脱していくユーザーもいらっしゃるかと思います。若輩者の取るに足らない意見かと思いますが１つ参考程度に心に止めておいていただけると幸いです。でも質問はいつもお世話になっています。また凄腕のパイソニスタの実力をこのサイトでみせつけちゃってください